# How can I change the placeholder color in Ant Design's Select component?

Tags: antd

I want to change the placeholder color of Select component in Ant Design.

I've tried these below, but none of them work.

```
.ant-select-selection {
  :placeholder-shown {
    color: red !important;
  }
  &:placeholder-shown {
    color: red !important;
  }
  :::placeholder {
    color: red !important;
  }
  color: black !important;
  &::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: blue !important;
  }
  &:placeholder {
    color: blue !important;
  }
  :placeholder {
    color: blue !important;
  }
  ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: blue !important;
  }
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: blue !important;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

I tried Hemanthvrm's suggestion, but it seems they changed the class name of the placeholder element to `.ant-select-selection-placeholder` in Ant Design 4. What worked for me was the following:

```
.ant-select-selection-placeholder {
  color: #f0f0f0;
}
```

Please mind there's an `opacity: 0.4;` by default on the placeholder element, so whatever color you use will look faded out.

Also mind this placeholder styling behavior is not consistent across different Ant components. For example, to style the placeholder of the date-range picker I had to do the following:

```
.ant-picker-input input::placeholder {
  color: #f0f0f0;
}
```

Bad news is, all these names might change again in a new major version. So better declare all the Ant related styles in one file, so your project becomes easily resilient to such changes.

Answer (score 4):

This will work

```
.ant-select-selection__placeholder{
  color : blue;
}
```

Working Sample
https://codesandbox.io/s/139lnkwwm3

Comment: This seems to work, thank you. I'm just wondering though, I thought that something like `__placeholder` is something auto-generated by Antd and isn't reliable to use? Is this the "correct" way to do this?

Comment: Totally fine and you can read it here https://pro.ant.design/docs/style ..take care of global pollution